# variables in variable names

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

If this title is bad sorry, but i don't have any idea to set it better.

I use a cms which has extra fields, i created 3 extrafields with labels: `box_title_1, box_title_2, box_title_3`

If want to get his values with a *for* loop, but the php can't check what i need, my php code is:

```
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++) {
     echo $this->element->box_title_ . $i;
}
```

Values what i get from my loop are only number (1,2,3)
If i call it direct `$this->element->box_title_1` then i see value, but i want to dynamic it, possible?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Why does it need to be dynamic when it is only 3 items?  Ten items I get.  But 3?  Just address them individually.

Comment: @greg_diesel there are only for example 3, i have much more :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@m_73, you can use this notation:

```
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++) {
     echo $this->element->{"box_title_" . $i};
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My pleasure, glad that worked. You can mark this answer as correct as well :)

Answer (score 0):

The link that @Niet posted has the information.

Here is a quick example to get you going

```
$type='last';
${"name_$type"}='johnson';

echo 'variable "$name_last" = '.$name_last;
```

this will output

```
variable "$name_last" = johnson
```

Answer (score -1):

perhaps the quickest way, maybe not the most secure, is to use [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

```
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++) {
     echo eval("$this->element->box_title_$i;");
}
```

Comment: I tried it already, but there i get this error message "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in"...